# Setting DatetimeIndex frequency, is it correct?

Tags: python, pandas

Having two time series like:

```
import pandas
from numpy import nan


# 1-minute period
index = pandas.date_range('1/1/2010', periods=8, freq='T')
series1 = pandas.Series([1., nan, nan, nan, nan, 2., nan, nan], index=index)

# 5-minutes period
index = pandas.date_range('1/1/2010', periods=2, freq='5T')
series5 = pandas.Series([1., 2.], index=index)
```

One of them is 1-minute based, the other is 5-minutes based. They both have the same values (excluding `nan`) at the same timestamps.

I don't want to keep `nan` values, so I drop them. However, dropping them also drops the frequency information from the `DatetimeIndex`:

```
series1 = series1.dropna()
print(series1.index.freq)
```

Now, I would really like to be able to differenciate two series like these: same timestamps, same values, but originating from different base frequencies.

In order to do so, I set the frequency back "by hand":

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset


series.index.freq = to_offset('T')
```

Question(s):

- Can anything go wrong? (i.e.: Pandas maybe expects to have that frequency set only for series with complete/filled indexes)
- If so, how else should I store that information?

Comment: @scott-boston I assume the `series1.dropna()` drops the `freq` from the index, because if you delete rows from the `DataFrame`, it will not have a set frequency

Answer (score 0):

In short: there is no good way to keep track of this information in the Series itself that I know off.
Here are a few alternatives:

## series attributes

you can add your own attribute to the series. Be warned that these will not be maintained when copying the Series or adding it to a DataFrame

```
series1._myfreq = 'T'
series5._myfreq = '5T'
```

## Index name

same caveat as for the attributes

```
series1.index.name = 'T'
series5.index.name = '5T'
```

## Outside of the `Series`

By choosing an appropriate variable name you can distinguish them, or you can keep the Series in a `dict`, with the `freq` as one of the other items of the dict

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my question was rather: "is there a problem in using the actual `series.index.freq` parameter to store that information? (i.e.: could that lead to unexpected problems/behavior when the series has an index with "holes" in it, like in this case?)

Comment: I don't know whether some algorithms use this `.freq` internally. You could look for that in the pandas source, or open an issue on it's github page